# Getting a cookiejar bug when I use requests module

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm a beginner, at the moment attempting to learn Python requests. And I've written a simple code, following a tutorial, using the module *requests*. This is the code:

```
import requests
url = "http://www.google.com"
response = requests.get(url)

print(f"Your request to {url} came back w/ status code {response.status_code}")
```

I've installed the module beforehand and followed the instructions. And I do get a response back from my terminal, telling me that the request came back with a status code 200. But before that, I get a:

```
UserWarning: http.cookiejar bug!
```

This is my full terminal:

```
λ python first_request.py
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\cookiejar.py:1626: UserWarning: http.cookiejar bug!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\cookiejar.py", line 1623, in make_cookies
    ns_cookies = self._cookies_from_attrs_set(
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\cookiejar.py", line 1580, in _cookies_from_attrs_set

    cookie = self._cookie_from_cookie_tuple(tup, request)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\cookiejar.py", line 1563, in _cookie_from_cookie_tuple
    return Cookie(version,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\http\cookiejar.py", line 794, in __init__
    self._rest = copy.copy(rest)
AttributeError: module 'copy' has no attribute 'copy'

  _warn_unhandled_exception()
Your request to http://www.google.com came back w/ status code 200
```

What does that mean?
I've looked into the cookiejar module and that it *defines classes for automatic handling of HTTP cookies*. But I don't really understand it yet. What do I need to do here exactly, to fix this User Warning?

Thank you!

Comment: You appear to have named a file something you shouldn't. Probably `copy.py`, possibly something else that clashes with something important, or perhaps you manually screwed with standard library files (something you should **never** do).

Comment: That's exactly it! I had a file named copy.py. Thank you! You could add this as an answer if you want, and I'll accept it! Again, thanks a bunch! I'll look into file naming right away!